# Spark 2.3.1 AWS EMR not returning data for some columns yet works in Athena/Presto and Spectrum

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr

I am using PySpark on Spark 2.3.1 on AWS EMR (Python 2.7.14)

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL data source example") \
    .config("hive.metastore.client.factory.class", "com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory") \
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true") \
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict") \
    .config("spark.debug.maxToStringFields", 100) \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()


spark.sql('select `message.country` from datalake.leads_notification where `message.country` is not null').show(10)
```

This returns no data, 0 rows found. 
Every value for each row in above table is returned Null. 
Data is stored in **PARQUET.**

When I ran same SQL query on AWS Athena/Presto or on AWs Redshift Spectrum then I get all column data returned correctly (most column values are not null).

This is the Athena SQL and Redshift SQL query that returns correct data:

```
select "message.country" from datalake.leads_notification where "message.country" is not null limit 10;
```

I use AWS Glue catalog in all cases.
The column above is NOT partitioned but the table is partitioned on other columns. I tried to use repair table, it did not help.
i.e. MSCK REPAIR TABLE datalake.leads_notification

i tried Schema Merge = True like so:

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("Python Spark SQL data source example") \
    .config("hive.metastore.client.factory.class", "com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory") \
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true") \
    .config("spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema", "true") \
    .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict") \
    .config("spark.debug.maxToStringFields", 200) \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()
```

No difference, still every value of one column is nulls even though some are  not null.

This column was added as the last column to the table so most data is indeed null but some rows are not null. The column is listed at last on the column list in catalog, sitting just above the partitioned columns.

Nevertheless Athena/Presto retrieves all non-null values OK and so does Redshift Spectrum too but alas EMR Spark 2.3.1 PySpark shows all values for this column as "null". All other columns in Spark are retrieved correctly.

Can anyone help me to debug this problem please?

Hive Schema is hard to cut and paste here due to output format.

```
***CREATE TABLE datalake.leads_notification(
  message.environment.siteorigin string, 
  dcpheader.dcploaddateutc string, 
  message.id int, 
  message.country string, 
  message.financepackage.id string, 
  message.financepackage.version string)
PARTITIONED BY ( 
  partition_year_utc string, 
  partition_month_utc string, 
  partition_day_utc string, 
  job_run_guid string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.serde.ParquetHiveSerDe' 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.parquet.MapredParquetOutputFormat'
LOCATION
  's3://blahblah/leads_notification/leads_notification/'
TBLPROPERTIES (
  'CrawlerSchemaDeserializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'CrawlerSchemaSerializerVersion'='1.0', 
  'UPDATED_BY_CRAWLER'='weekly_datalake_crawler', 
  'averageRecordSize'='3136', 
  'classification'='parquet', 
  'compressionType'='none', 
  'objectCount'='2', 
  'recordCount'='897025', 
  'sizeKey'='1573529662', 
  'spark.sql.create.version'='2.2 or prior', 
  'spark.sql.sources.schema.numPartCols'='4', 
  'spark.sql.sources.schema.numParts'='3', 
  'spark.sql.sources.schema.partCol.0'='partition_year_utc', 
  'spark.sql.sources.schema.partCol.1'='partition_month_utc', 
  'spark.sql.sources.schema.partCol.2'='partition_day_utc', 
  'spark.sql.sources.schema.partCol.3'='job_run_guid', 
  'typeOfData'='file')***
```

Last 3 columns all have the same problems in Spark:

```
message.country string, 
message.financepackage.id string, 
message.financepackage.version string
```

All return OK in Athena/Presto and Redshift Spectrum using same catalog.

I apologize for my editing.

thank you

Comment: Can you please add the schema of the table to the question.
You can use this command using hive cli:
show create table datalake.leads_notification;

Comment: edited, had to cut columns, it is a very large table schema, 100+ columns

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do step 5 schema inspection:
http://www.openkb.info/2015/02/how-to-build-and-use-parquet-tools-to.html

my bet is these new column names in parquet definition are either upper case (while other column names are lower case) or new column names in parquet definition are either lower case (while other column names are upper case)

see [Spark issues reading parquet files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47398794/spark-issues-reading-parquet-files)
https://medium.com/@an_chee/why-using-mixed-case-field-names-in-hive-spark-sql-is-a-bad-idea-95da8b6ec1e0

Comment: THANK YOU! This seems to have solved the problem, I will post the final session config for all to review below.

Comment: @AcidRider please accept the answer if it works, thanks!

Comment: done, thank you very much, a major relief for a production deployment!!

Answer (score 1):

```
spark = SparkSession \
        .builder \
        .appName("Python Spark SQL data source example") \
        .config("hive.metastore.client.factory.class", "com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory") \
        .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition", "true") \
        .config("spark.sql.parquet.mergeSchema", "true") \
        .config("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet", "false") \
        .config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict") \
        .config("spark.debug.maxToStringFields", 200) \
        .enableHiveSupport() \
        .getOrCreate()
```

This is the solution: note the

```
 .config("spark.sql.hive.convertMetastoreParquet", "false")
```

The schema columns are all in lower case and the schema was created by AWS Glue, not by my custom code so I dont really know what caused the problem so using the above is probably the safe default setting when schema creation is not directly under your control. This is a major trap, IMHO, so I hope this will help someone else in future. 
Thanks to **tooptoop4** who pointed out the article:

https://medium.com/@an_chee/why-using-mixed-case-field-names-in-hive-spark-sql-is-a-bad-idea-95da8b6ec1e0